# Python loop : idx for idx (rewrite to javascript)

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to re-write some Python code to Javascript.

I can't figure out how to rewrite this part :

```
zone_indices = [[idx for idx, val in enumerate(classified) if zone + 1 == val] for zone in range(maxz)]
```

**idx for idx, val** : what does it mean to put **idx** at the beginning ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"idx" is usually short for **index.**

Python loops allows items in a nested list to be accessed directly like so:

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> 
>>> for a,b in lst:
        print a,b

1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Using enumerate in Python allows for something similar:

```
>>> for idx,val in enumerate(['a','b','c']):
        print('index of ' + val + ': ' + str(idx))

index of a: 0
index of b: 1
index of c: 2
```

The equivalent of `enumerate(array)` in JavaScript is `array.entries()`, and can be used in much the same way as Python:

```
zone_indices = []

for (let i = 0; i < maxz.length, i++) {
    for (let [idx, val] of classified.entries()) {
        if (zone+1 === val) {
            zone_indices.push(idx);
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an iterable and you want to iterate over it and you need only **values** of its items. You can use ordinary list comprehension:

```
[x for x in it]
```

But if you need **value and index** of an item, you probably want to use `enumerate` with iterable. And in this case it will look like this:

```
[(ix, val) for ix, val in it]
```

Here, at the left side of `for` keyword you may take `ix`, `val` or both in any order. But at the right side `val` always should follow the `ix`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code :

```
zone_indices = [[idx for idx, val in enumerate(classified) if zone + 1 == val] for zone in range(maxz)]
```

is equivalent to this:

```
zone_indices = []

for zone in range(maxz):
    for idx, val in enumerate(classified):
         if zone + 1 == val:
            zone_indices.append(idx)
```

I think now it must be easy to covert to it JS. It may be something like below:

```
zone_indices = []
for(let zone=0; zone< maxz ; zone++){
    for(idx in classified){
        if (zone + 1 === classified[idx]){
            zone_indices.push(idx)
        }
    } 
}
```